# Invoking std::thread with pointer to freestanding function

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, function-pointers

I tried to invoke `std::thread` perfect forwarding constructor (`template< class Function, class... Args > explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );`) with a pointer to function (NOT a pointer to *member* function), as shown in the following M(N)WE:

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>

static void foo(std::string query, int & x)
{
  while(true);
}

int main() {
 int i = 1;
 auto thd = std::thread(&foo, std::string("bar"), i);
 thd.join();
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/g/Cwi6wd

Why does the code not compile on GCC, Clang and MSVC, complaining about a missing overload of `invoke` (or similar names)?
A function argument is a pointer to a function, so it should be a `Callable`, right?

Please note: I know that using a lambda would solve the problem; I want to understand why the problem arises.

Comment: @Ron: Not on my VS2015.

Comment: I am using the 2013 version which doesn't support the C++14 standard. Probably time to upgrade.

Comment: @Ron: it is C++11, actually... but you should upgrade anyway because support of C++11 by VS2013 is partial (I remember that when I switched to VS2015 I forgot frustration and nightmares about things that should have worked and they didn't, especially for code portable across compilers)

Comment: @Ron, if I recall correctly older VS's allowed binding lvalue references to modifiable temporaries ( probably, the int is stored in a tuple internally ), hence it compiles

Comment: Nit: Not a MNWE because the ``std::string`` argument is not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::thread` stores copies of the arguments it is passed. Which as [Massimiliano Janes pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070683/817643), is evaluated in the context of the caller to a temporary. For all intents and purposes, it's better to consider it as a const object.

Since `x` is a non-const reference, it cannot bind to the argument being fed to it by the thread.

If you want `x` to refer to `i`, you need to use `std::reference_wrapper`.

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

static void foo(std::string , int & )
{
  while(true);
}

int main() {
 int i = 1;
 auto thd = std::thread(foo, std::string("bar"), std::ref(i));
 thd.join();
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60164c218aac8615)</kbd>

The utility `std::ref` will create it on the fly.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - They are copied/moved by value. For all intents and purposed... But I'll clarify

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - Yes, I heard you the first time. And already edited

Comment: "it's better to consider it as a const object" can you elaborate ? are you suggesting to avoid taking an rvalue reference ? if yes, why ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - I do. Because it creates ad-hoc "state" for the thread. If the thread needs a modifiable integer, it should be part of the callable. Not an rvalue reference to a temporary created outside the thread context itself.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - Or at the very least, it should be a by-value parameter. Because that makes clear the fact that i's local to the thread. The rvalue reference is an eyebrow raiser.

Comment: ok got it, although I'm not totally persuaded; I agree that taking an && buys you nothing more than sparing a (cheap) move at the cost of less code clarity; but consider the case when foo() is an existing function taking an rvalue reference ( for some good reason ), I don't think wrapping it would be justifiable in this case...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes - Probably won't be worth to wrap it. But I'm against designing it like that for a thread if given the chance.

Comment: ``std::bind`` works as well: ``std::thread(std::bind(foo, std::string("bar"), i))``, as does a lambda. I can see why they chose ``decay_copy`` (to avoid hidden data races), but still find the lack of consistency a bit unfortunate.

Answer (score 3):

std::thread constructor performs a decay_copy on its arguments before invoking the callable perfect-forwarding the result to it; in your foo, you're trying to bind a lvalue reference (int& x) to an rvalue reference (to the temporary), hence the error; either take an int, an int const& or an int&& instead ( or pass a reference wrapper ).

Answer (score 2):

Following on from [StoryTeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070654/2015579), a lambda may offer a clearer way to express this:

I think there are a couple of scenarios:

If we really do want to pass a reference to `i` in our outer scope:

```
 auto thd = std::thread([&i]
 {
     foo("bar", i);
 });
```

And if foo taking a reference just happens to be an historical accident:

```
 auto thd = std::thread([]() mutable
 {
     int i = 1;
     foo("bar", i);
 });
```

In the second form, we have localised the variable `i` and reduced the risk that it will be read or written to outside the thread (which would be UB).

Comment: Oh, I love the daisy chain of answers that is happening here :) +1 for those points about clarity. My thoughts exactly

Comment: "Please note: I know that using a lambda would solve the problem; I want to understand why the problem arises."

Comment: @Astrinus I see your point. The reason for needing `std::ref` is that the function object built by `std::thread` cannot 'know' whether it needs to capture by reference or by value, so by value is assumed (because it's safer and more logical) unless the argument type is a specialisation of `std::reference_wrapper`. Essentially specifying `[&i]` in a lambda is equivalent to passing the return type of `std::ref(i)`